# cifs mount not working using fstab on RHEL6

Tags: linux, rhel6, fstab

I had a line in my fstab file that until this morning allowed me to read and write to a windows share (dummy IP address is shown below)

```
//111.111.1.111/ecc /mnt/nas2 cifs user,uid=500,gid=500,username=*****,password=*****,file_mode=0666,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

This morning, for some unexplained reason, it does not work (no reboot) and the filesystem on the share does not mount.  I can ping the share OK.  I can mount the share using mount.cifs from the command line but I always have trouble getting write permissions with this approach.  If I try to source the fstab I get this:

-bash: /boot: is a directory
-bash: /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home: Permission denied
-bash: /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_swap: Permission denied
-bash: tmpfs: command not found
-bash: devpts: command not found
-bash: sysfs: command not found
-bash: proc: command not found
-bash: //111.111.1.111/ecc: No such file or directory

I have not edited fstab but it seems to be failing to do most things.  How do I get fstab working again?

Comment: chkconfig --list netfs

Comment: not quite sure what I'm meant to do here but using    chkconfig --list netfs , I get the result: netfs           0:off 1:off 2:off 3:on 4:on 5:on 6:off .  This doesn't mean a whole lot to me.

Comment: why you are using user option in your fstab without any values? try to remove that and just use username and password